# OR Function of Excel with Error Values

Tags: excel-2010

I want to apply one OR Function in excel with some cells, but Excel is having #N/A(Error Value) in the containing cells, where i want to apply the formula.
Is it possible to apply OR Formula with the cells containing Error Values.

```
=OR((A1 = "T"),(B1 = "T"),(C1 = "T"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IFERROR` function ([reference](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-iferror-function)) to capture any errors in your source cells and replace them with a default value, say `"F"`:

```
=OR((IFERROR(A1, "F") = "T"),(IFERROR(B1, "F") = "T"),(IFERROR(C1, "F") = "T"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried with following formula and now it is working: